# How can I vote for a Proxy on Cleos?

Tags: cleos, voting, proxy

I would like to delegate my votes to an EOS Proxy instead, how can I do this using the Cleos tool?

Answer (score 3):

Confirm you're connecting to the main chain. This can be accomplished with the cleos command 
`cleos -u http://mainnet.genereos.io:80 get info`

In the -u switch we are specifying which Block Producer we'd like to connect to, you can change this to whomever you like. 
In the response you should expect

`"chain_id": "aca376f206b8fc25a6ed44dbdc66547c36c6c33e3a119ffbeaef943642f0e906`

### Finding your account name

An account is already created for you on the EOS main net if you participated in the ICO, we can find your account name by looking up your PUBLIC key. E.g.

`cleos -u http://mainnet.genereos.io:80 get accounts *Insert EOS Public Key*`

`{
  "account_names": [
    "*Your account name*"
  ]
}`

This will return a list of all the accounts associated with that public key, we're only expecting one. Copy your account name and keep it handy in your clipboard or write it down.

### Delegate your Vote

Finally, you can delegate your vote. 
`cleos -u http://mainnet.genereos.io:80 system voteproducer proxy *Your account name* *Your proxies account name*`

You can double check this has been successful by running command
`cleos -u http://mainnet.genereos.io:80 get account *Your account name*`
Which will return account details, including your selected proxy.